# How can I draw route walking (dot)

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-polyline, gmsmapview

```
let legs = itineraries[0]["legs"].arrayValue
for route in legs
{
    let mode = route["mode"].string ?? "-"
    let routeOverviewPolyline = route["legGeometry"].dictionary
    let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
    let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)

    polyline.strokeColor = color
    polyline.strokeWidth = 4
    polyline.map = self.indexView.mapView
}
```

This code is used to draw lines.
Like in google maps application, I want to plot the walking route. Dotted and round.
I couldn't find an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension GMSMapView {

    func drawPolyline(_ pathString: String) -> GMSPolyline? {
      guard let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: pathString) else { return nil }
      let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
      polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
      polyline.geodesic = true
      let styles: [GMSStrokeStyle] = [.solidColor(.black), .solidColor(.clear)]
      let scale = 1.0 / projection.points(forMeters: 1.0, at: camera.target)
      let dashLength = NSNumber(value: 3.5 * Float(scale))
      let gapLength = NSNumber(value: 3.0 * Float(scale))
      polyline.spans = GMSStyleSpans(path, styles, [dashLength, gapLength], .rhumb)
      polyline.map = self
      return polyline
   }
}
```